# Selecting the email that invoked a rule that runs a VBA script

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a rule that runs a VBA script. Within that VBA script i need to get the text from within the body of the email that invoked the rule. How would I go about doing this?

Cant find anywhere that has a way to do this at all really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The item which triggered the rule is passed as a parameter:

```
Public Sub RuleTest(mail as MailItem)
    MsgBox mail.HTMLBody
End Sub
```

In addition, there are three main ways for working with bodies in Outlook:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx).
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx).
3. Word editor. The Inspector class provides the [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property which returns an instance of the Document class from the Word object model which represents the message body. Outlook uses Word as an email editor.

You can read more about that in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) .